# C++ code using the "libstudxml" library won't compile, or link

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use the libstudxml library:

[libstudxml: modern C++ XML API](http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/libstudxml/)

[Github Repository: windoze/libstudxml](https://github.com/windoze/libstudxml)

But my code won't compile, I'm probably not link with the library...  Does anyone know if I need to link with the libstudxml library? or what i'm doing wrong?

This is how I'm compiling:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

Am I missing something?

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -l??????
```

This is the code I'm trying to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <xml/parser>
#include <xml/serializer>
int main()
{
  std::ifstream ifs( "file.xml" );
  xml::parser p( ifs, "file.xml" );
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
/tmp/ccLqLaZq.o: In function 'main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xa9): 
undefined reference to 'xml::parser::~parser()'
/tmp/ccLqLaZq.o: In function 'xml::parser::parser(std::istream&, 
std::string const&, unsigned short)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3xml6parserC2ERSiRKSst[_ZN3xml6parserC5ERSiRKSst]+0xd5):  
undefined reference to 'xml::parser::init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status﻿
```

Comment: Have tried `-lstudxml`?

Comment: You must specify without prefix and file extension the name of the library.

Comment: Oh crap!. `-lstudxml` works... I tried `-llibstudxml`, `-lxml` and `-lXML` but not `-lstudxml`... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command needed to compile and link the code is:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lstudxml
```

*Thanks to Oleg Andriyanov.*

And to run the executable, you need:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./a.out
```